# Why am I getting a bottom overflowed when keyboard is on?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

hi i want someone to help me for this problem in flutter ,I will put the picture to understand
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yv9EQ.png)

thanks

Comment: [this](https://medium.com/zipper-studios/the-keyboard-causes-the-bottom-overflowed-error-5da150a1c660) can help

Comment: wrap your code in `SingleChildScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your page in a Listview() widget or a Single ChildScrollview

Answer (score 0):

This means that your widget needs space more than the space that is available. You can either change the size of the widget, or make your page/widget scrollable, which will give it more vertical space. To do that, wrap your widget/page with a **SingleChildScrollView** widget.

Comment: tanks man for your answer , i find the solution in this code :" resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false" ,